# how to use like any with array of string JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, sql-like

I'm trying to consult using HIBERNATE and JPA.

this is the native query and it works on postgres

```
select * from table tb where upper(tb.column1) like any(array[?1]);
```

but when i run using jpa I get the following error

> [42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: text ~~ record
>     Dica: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

I see that it is because the hibernate run the query like this:

```
select * from table tb where upper(tb.column1) like any(array[('%text1%', '%texte2%')]);
```

and it should be withou the '()' like this:

```
select * from table tb where upper(tb.column1) like any(array['%text1%', '%texte2%']);
```

Here is how I'm running on JPA

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT column1 FROM table1 WHERE column1 LIKE ANY(ARRAY[?1])")
List<String> example(List<String> valores);
```

How can I solve it....

Comment: The ANY operator must be preceded by one of the following comparison operators =, <=, >, <, > and <>
That is the reason that is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

`select *  from (select unnest([array]) as colum_text from [table]) as temporal where temporal.colum_text like '%[value to search]%'`